# CIDR blocks for AWS VPC and its subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr

I have a CIDR block of 172.30.0.0/21 and need to create 2 private subnets and then 2 public subnets for it.

At first I created:
for private: ["172.30.8.0/21", "172.30.16.0/21"]
for public: ["172.30.0.0/22", "172.30.8.0/22"]

but then I got the following errors:

```
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '172.30.8.0/22' is invalid.
10:59:12    status code: 400, request id: 9***
10:59:12  
10:59:12    on .terraform/modules/vpc-us-west-2/main.tf line 335, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
10:59:12   335: resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
10:59:12  
10:59:12  
10:59:12  
10:59:12  Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '172.30.16.0/21' is invalid.
10:59:12    status code: 400, request id: d**
10:59:12  
10:59:12    on .terraform/modules/vpc-us-west-2/main.tf line 363, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
10:59:12   363: resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
10:59:12  
10:59:12  
10:59:12  
10:59:12  Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '172.30.8.0/21' is invalid.
10:59:12    status code: 400, request id: d**
10:59:12  
10:59:12    on .terraform/modules/vpc-us-west-2/main.tf line 363, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
10:59:12   363: resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
```

So NOW:-

- I created:

for private:["172.30.0.0/21", "172.30.4.0/21"]
for public: ["172.30.0.0/22", "172.30.2.0/22"]

are they fine? will they work and fix the errors?

- This is part of my code:

```
# List of private subnets to create in the environment, e.g. ["172.18.0.0/21", "172.18.8.0/21"]
variable "private_subnets-west-2" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["172.30.0.0/22", "172.30.6.0/23"]
}

# List of public subnets to create in the environment, e.g. ["172.18.168.0/22", "172.18.172.0/22"]
variable "public_subnets-west-2" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["172.30.0.0/22", "172.30.4.0/23"]
}
```

(the values currently in the subnets, I am not sure they work)

and these are the subnets I need to create. Again my CIDR is 172.30.0.0/21

Update: my private subnets work fine:

```
# List of private subnets to create in the environment, e.g. ["172.18.0.0/21", "172.18.8.0/21"]
variable "private_subnets-west-2" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["172.30.0.0/22", "172.30.6.0/23"]
}
```

However, I have been trying different subnets for my public one's since an hour now, and cannot find the proper ones:

```
# List of public subnets to create in the environment, e.g. ["172.18.168.0/22", "172.18.172.0/22"]
variable "public_subnets-west-2" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["172.30.0.64/26", "172.30.0.128/26"]
}
```

keep on getting errors for conflict or invalid:

```
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '172.30.0.128/26' conflicts with another subnet
        status code: 400, request id:

  on .terraform/modules/vpc-us-west-2/main.tf line 335, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 335: resource "aws_subnet" "public" {

Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '172.30.0.64/26' conflicts with another subnet
        status code: 400, request id: 

  on .terraform/modules/vpc-us-west-2/main.tf line 335, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 335: resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
```

I have been stuck for long, if someone can help me and tell me exactly which 2 subnets I can use, it would be great help!

Comment: To split a /21 into 4 subnets, the 4 subnets need to be /23. `172.30.0.0/23`, `172.30.2.0/23`, `172.30.4.0/23`, `172.30.6.0/23`. See the results of the subnet calculator here: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=172.30.0.0&mask1=21&mask2=23

Comment: @jordanm thanks.. however using the same /23 for both public and private will be fine?

Comment: @myra A specific CIDR range can only be used for one subnet. All subnets within a VPC can communicate with each other, so they need non-overlapping CIDR ranges.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so how to I know which one's to know? can u help please

Comment: @Myra Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "how to I know which one's to know"?

Comment: The CIDR range on a VPC is totally within the **private IP address range**. To make a **public subnet**, edit the Route Table associated with the desired subnet and send traffic with a destination of `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet Gateway associated with the VPC. This effectively makes the subnet "public". Then, any resources within the subnet that should communicate with the Internet should be assigned a Public IP address (eg with an Elastic IP). They will they have both a public and a private IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sorry for the unclear, I did not notice that. I just made edits in the question to clarify my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `172.30.0.0/21` CIDR goes from `172.30.0.0` to `172.30.7.255`.

If you want to divide this equally into 4 subnets, you can use:

- `172.30.0.0/23`, which goes from `172.30.0.0` to `172.30.1.255`
- `172.30.2.0/23`, which goes from `172.30.2.0` to `172.30.3.255`
- `172.30.4.0/23`, which goes from `172.30.4.0` to `172.30.5.255`
- `172.30.6.0/23`, which goes from `172.30.6.0` to `172.30.7.255`

@jordanm gave this link to a great CIDR calculator: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=172.30.0.0&mask1=21&mask2=23

Comment: thanks.. however I am still confused. pls see the update I posted on question. I am actually very new to this so I am stuck on it for a while but need to solve asap.

Comment: The above subnets allow **equal division of IP addresses** between the subnets. Your updated question has a mixture of `/22`, `/23` and `/26` that do not mix well together. For example, a `/22` takes half the IP address from a `/21` range. I suggest that you stick to using _only_ the `/23` addresses above so that all IP addresses are fully provisioned. Alternatively, talk to your networking team to confirm how you would like the IP addresses arranged.

Answer (score 2):

The error - "Invalid subnet" is given for 172.30.8.x network, as the 172.30.8.x is outside the range supported by the allocated address space (172.30.0.0/21) .

**Here is the explanation:**

**172.30.0.0/21**  is the available address space.

It can also be written as:

**172.30.0.0 / 255.255.248.0**

The range of IP addresses that belong to this network are:

**172.30.0.0 to 172.30.7.255**

Any subnet that lies within this boundary (172.30.0.0 to 172.30.7.255) will be accepted by AWS.

**Some examples of subnets that will be acceptable for the given CIDR space are:**

172.30.1.0 / 24

172.30.2.0 / 30

172.30.7.0 / 28

172.30.7.248 / 29

Comment: thank u.. however I just tried those subnets and I got error:
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '172.30.7.0/28' conflicts with another subnet
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '172.30.7.248/29' is invalid.
        status code: 400, request id:
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '172.30.2.0/30' is invalid.
        status code: 400, request id:
Error: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '172.30.1.0/24' conflicts with another subnet

Comment: @gopinath provided _example_ ranges. They were not intended to be used together.